# How to repeat a statement N times (simple loop)

Tags: loops, d

I need to perform an action N times. What is the best way in D to do it?

```
for(uint i=0; i<N; i++)
   action();

foreach(uint i; 0.. N)
   action();
```

maybe something better? Ideally I'd want something like Groovy's / Ruby's `times` e.g

```
N.times {
   action();
}
```

is it possible?

Comment: Btw, your second example must use `foreach` rather than `for` and you can actually remove `uint`. A convention used in D for loop iterators that need not be referenced in the loop is to name them `_`. So it becomes `foreach (_; 0 .. N)`

Comment: I'd really recommend downloading the free reference and reading it.  All of this is answered fairly early on in the book.  Your first works.  Your second would be for _ in 0..N { ... }.  The third is possible, but I'm not sure if the times extension is normal.  I know there's an example of exactly that in the WWDC presentations, Introductory Swift I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible

```groovy
import std.stdio;
import std.traits;

void foo()
{
    writeln("Do It!");
}

void times(T,N)(N n, T action) if (isCallable!T && isIntegral!N)
{
    static if (ParameterTypeTuple!action.length == 1 
           && isIntegral!(ParameterTypeTuple!action[0]))
        foreach (i; 0 .. n)
            action(i);
    else
        foreach (i; 0 .. n)
            action();
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    10.times(&foo);
    10.times({writeln("Do It!");});
    10.times((uint n){writeln(n + 1, " Round");});
}
```

version with arguments support:

```groovy
import std.stdio;
import std.traits;

void foo()
{
    writeln("Do It!");
}

struct Step {
    alias n this;
    size_t n;
    this(size_t i)
    {
        n = i + 1;
    }
}

struct Index {
    alias n this;
    size_t n;
}

void times(T,N,A...)(N n, T action, A args) if (isCallable!T && isIntegral!N)
{
    alias PTTAction = ParameterTypeTuple!action;
    static if (PTTAction.length >= 1)
    {
        alias FP = PTTAction[0];
        static if (is(Index == FP) || is(Step == FP))
            foreach (i; 0 .. n)
                action(FP(i), args);
        else
            action(args);
    }
    else
        foreach (i; 0 .. n)
            action();
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    10.times(&foo);
    10.times({writeln("Do It!");});
    10.times((Step n){writeln(n, " Step");});
    10.times((Index n, string msg){writeln(n, msg);}, " Index");
    stdin.readln;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

for better performance you could use alias template parameter for action:

```groovy
void times(alias action,N)(N n) if (isCallable!action && isIntegral!N)
{
    static if (ParameterTypeTuple!action.length == 1 
           && isIntegral!(ParameterTypeTuple!action[0]))
        foreach (i; 0 .. n)
            action(i);
    else
        foreach (i; 0 .. n)
            action();
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    10.times!(foo);
    10.times!({writeln("Do It!");});
    10.times!((uint n){writeln(n + 1, " Round");});
}
```

Comment: OK, Thank you :-) Especially the first version is really simple to follow and I love it.

Comment: Because passing by name (alias action) does not need dereferencing action. But I am not sure. And maybe there is more reasons, so It would be interresing make this a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this?

```groovy
void loop(int n, void delegate() func)
{
    foreach (i; 0 .. n)
    {
        func();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```groovy
loop(10, {        
    writeln("Hello World!");
});
```